# Regular Expression IE lookahead bug

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, validation

I am trying to define the regular expression required for my ASP.NET validator to run properly. Currently with the expression below I am able to properly validate the following sample string in firefox but not in IE

`12{2}12{0-9}1{12,13}`

using

`(({\d+\})*|(\d)*|({(\d+,)+\d+\})*|({(\d+)\-(\d+)\})*)+`

After doing some research it seems that this is due to the lookahead bug but since I am fairly new to using regex I do not understand how I can modify it properly to work around the bug?

Please feed me with higher knowledge!!

EDIT:
The expression must match these three optional individual component that can be in the string in any order. I tried to come up with an expression describing each individual component and then merging them into a single expression.

```
{n} regex {\d+\}  to match sample {423} optional digits

{n,n,n} regex {(\d+,)+\d+\} to match sample set of digit {24,25,26}

{n-n} regex {(\d+)\-(\d+)\} to match sample range of {0-9}

individual digits (\d) to match sample 232
```

EDIT 2:
In the end I will be using this expression and a special thanks to woohoo

`((\d*\#*\**)*\{((\d*\#*\**)+|(\d*\#*\**)+\-(\d*\#*\**)+|((\d*\#*\**)+\,)+(\d*\#*\**)+)\}(\d*\#*\**)*)+`

the expression supports digits # and * at every position.

Comment: Is this done in C# on the server, or in JavaScript in the browser?  If C# on the server, then the choice of browser would have no impact on this.

Comment: It is done in the browser and on the server since I am using an asp.net regular expression validator component but its failing on the browser

Comment: You might be better off removing the C# and asp.net tags, and adding javascript and ie tags.  I would also view source in the browser, and copy the javascript and paste it into this post.

Comment: All the other regular expression validations are done using the asp.net native components I would like to be able to keep this one in the same format than the other ones to ease futur maintenance

Comment: When I said "remove tags", I was referring to the tags on this post, not the HTML/ASP.NET tags in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the regular expression you posted above has some errors, and it looks too complicated for what you try to achieve. I would do it this way:

```
\d+\{(\d+|\d+\-\d+|\d+\,\d+)\}
```

eventually you can add the + sign to match one or more of these,

```
(\d+\{(\d+|\d+\-\d+|\d+\,\d+)\})+
```

or, if you want to match a specific number of those, use {m,n} quantitative expression:

```
(\d+\{(\d+|\d+\-\d+|\d+\,\d+)\}){3,}
```

In this case I made it to match exactly 3 pieces.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I agree with you the expression i have is complex most likely too complex for what it is supposed to do. I put an edit to give more details on it. I will give a shot to your proposed ones right now.

Comment: Did some small edit to your expression (\d*\{(\d+|\d+\-\d+|(\d+\,)+\d+)\}\d*)+ it now seems to behave fine it much simple and easier to read now. I want to perform some further tests before I mark the answer.